# What recommended festivals are there in San Francisco during Aug- Sep?

Tags: festivals, san-francisco

I would like to go to some cool festivals in SF in AUG or SEP, something like [this](http://www.sfoutsidelands.com/home/), are there any stuff like this?

Comment: could you be more specific? what sort of things are you in to, how long are you there for? It's a big city with a LOT happening.

Comment: I am going to be there for a month ( AUG 20th -  SEP 29th).. music festivals and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## August

### Outside Lands Festival

Music, Food, Wine, Beer, & Art Festival in Golden Gate Park.

### San Francisco Shakespeare Festival

The genius of Shakespeare in San Francisco's most relaxing setting. Admission is free every Saturday and Sunday through the month of September. Arrive early for a good seat; shows begin at 1:30pm.

### San Jose Jazz Festival

With over 80 artists and more than 100,000 attendees, the San Jose Jazz Festival holds a well-earned ranking among the best Bay Area jazz events. This live music festival not only includes fantastic performances, but also activities like a jazz brunch, master classes, a club crawl, mural painting and after-hours entertainment. Located in the heart of downtown, the San Jose Jazz Festival is easily accessible from San Francisco by both freeways and CalTrain, making it an ideal and convenient weekend activity.

## September

### San Francisco Fringe Festival

An ever-changing collection of unusual and lively experimental theater pieces.
Ghirardelli Square Chocolate Festival
Sample the sinful fruits of chocolatiers like Ghirardelli and others in the 8th Annual Ghirardelli Square Chocolate Festival. Admission to this San Francisco festival is free, but five chocolate tasting samples require a $6 ticket.

### San Francisco Blues Festival

Join local blues artists and blues legends in a weekend of outdoor performances on Saturday and Sunday from 11am - 6pm each day. Tickets are $25 per day in advance, $30 at the door, special two-day tickets for $40.

### Folsom Street Fair

In one of San Francisco's most beloved examples of exhibitionism, see the latest in bondage techniques, products and fashion. The fair runs officially from 11am - 6pm, but the bars and restaurants in SoMa stay crowded with latex and leather wearing voyeurs all night long, especially the mainstay Stud Bar.

Source: http://www.sanfrancisco.com/festivals/